Multiple regression model for devices located in different countries
How can I deal with a regression problem where I have a group of time-series signals (40) and predict a few features, the situation is that the data comes from different devices located around the world that measure internal-external temperatures/voltages/current/power consumption/ etc..
When I build a model for each location-device I get good results, but when trying to combine all the data from all the different locations into a single model, the performance is much worse.
Given that the signals measured are the same, why is it giving worse results, should I try another approach? add some sort of identifier to each device, or should I stick with building a model for each device?
I've tried SGD Regression, XGboost and Catboost.

yes you should add an identifier for the device, then you should be able to combine data where appropriate (and isolate where not).  There is a separate question for you to uncover why location makes a difference

@seanv507 location shouldn't make a difference that's what's confusing me, the only main difference would be the external temperature. But that is a feature included in the model

maybe you can take a time series and then see the impact of changing the location alone. then you can try to correlate that to other variables (humidity/daylight/voltage/... ?)
